# I'm having trouble with this code, the image names are correct; what do I do? How can I solve this Traffic Light Sequence?

Tags: arrays, if-statement

I have been trying to create a JavaScript traffic light sequence as an experiment. The code seems right but for some reason, it's not working. Can someone please help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>

<body>

  <h1>Traffic Lights Task 3 JavaScript Controlled Assesment 2017</h1> 

  <img id="Traffic_Lights" src="RED.png">
  <button type="button" onclick="changeLights()">Change Lights</button>   

<script>

    var image = ["RED.png","AMBERRED.png","GREEN.png","AMBER.png"];

    var Traffic_Light_Sequence = document.getElementById('Traffic_Lights');

    function changeLights() {

      if (Traffic_Lights.src == "RED.png") {
      Traffic_Lights.src = image[1];
    } else if (Traffic_Lights.src == "AMBERRED.png") { 
      Traffic_Lights.src = image[2];
    } else if (Traffic_Lights.src == "GREEN.png") { 
      Traffic_Lights.src = image[3];
    } else {
      Traffic_Lights.src = image[0]

    }
    } 

  </script>  
</body>
```

Comment: I've got some questions regarding your code: What is the difference between the variable `Traffic_Lights` and the variable `Traffic_Light_Sequence`? Why is the variable `Traffic_Lights` not initialized anywhere? Why is `Traffic_Light_Sequence` not initialized until the end of your function?

Comment: The image id = Traffic_Lights

Comment: I'm asking about the javascript variable named `Traffic_Lights`, not the html element with id set to `"Traffic_Lights"`.

Comment: "Traffic_Lights" is supposed to show what stage the traffic light sequence is. e.g. if the stage of the traffic light sequence ("Traffic_Lights") is Red, then Image should change to the next stage in the sequence. Sadly it doesn't seem to work...